# geom_area resulting in horizontal lines where area fill should be

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to fill the area below and above a separating line by using geom_area. However, once I use the code, I get these weird horizontal lines below the graph-line and the area is not being filled. Furthermore, geom_ribbon is also not showing on the graph.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Concentration, y = OD600_avg)) +
  geom_area(colour = "black", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = Concentration, ymin = OD600_avg - OD600_sdv, ymax = OD600_avg + OD600_sdv), fill = "firebrick", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(colour = "red", size = 1, aes(x = Concentration, y = OD600_avg, group = 1))
```

Data:

```
my_data <- data.frame("Concentration" = c("0", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55"), 
                   "OD600_avg" = c("0.8", "0.17", "0.15", "0.14", "0.137", "0.12", "0.11", "0.09", "0.08", "0.08", "0.08", "0.08"),
                   "OD600_sdv" = c("0.05", "0.004", "0.002", "0.005", "0.008", "0.005", "0.007", "0.02", "0.011", "0.02", "0.004", "0.004"))
```

Here is the result:

[Result of ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrM7v.png)

Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: your data is not numeric, they are characters. Try correcting them first.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: I added the answer. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not `numeric`, they are `characters`. The following works

```
my_data <- data.frame(Concentration = seq(0,55,5), 
                           OD600_avg = c(0.8, 0.17, 0.15, 0.14, 0.137, 0.12, 0.11, 0.09, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08),
                          OD600_sdv = c(0.05, 0.004, 0.002, 0.005, 0.008, 0.005, 0.007, 0.02, 0.011, 0.02, 0.004, 0.004))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Concentration, y = OD600_avg)) +
  geom_area(colour = "black", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = Concentration, ymin = OD600_avg - OD600_sdv, ymax = OD600_avg + OD600_sdv), fill = "firebrick", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(colour = "red", size = 1, aes(x = Concentration, y = OD600_avg, group = 1))
```

[image]